# angular 2+ Promises, Observable and async pipe

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I'm working on my first project in angular 4 and ran into a small problem.

When I make a call to the server, there is a delay and I've learned to use async pipe to display the data that I fetch from the server.

But the problem I've ran into is that let's say for example, I made a HTTP call to the server and now I'm waiting for the information to comeback from the server.  But I need that information to do some number crunching.  So the variables that I've assigned which are waiting for the information from the server are coming back as undefined because the code at run-time gets executed and there is no value available for them to be assigned to.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.settings = this.settingsService.getSettings();
    console.log("Logging Settings: " + this.settings);  // ends up being undefined
  }

onDoSomething(){
    return this.settings * gazillion;  // doesn't work 
}
```

what would be a proper way to make the service call and let the method DoSomething know to hold off till you get the settings?  Also, If you were using the settings through out your app how would you store it so you are not constantly making HTTP call each time you need the settings.

My intuition was to have the app.componenet.ts make the call and store.

Thanks!

Comment: For your second question, you would typically store the settings in a singleton service. This way anything in your app can access the service to get the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the do or map operator depending on what you're actually trying to achieve:

```
this.settings = this.settingsService.getSettings().do(settings => this.doSomething(settings));
```

if you just want a "side effect", as in you dont actually want to affect the data you're sending the the display, you just want to do something else with it unrelated to displaying it, but you need it to happen at a certain point in the sequence (i will often use do() to hide a pagewide content loading popup or something). it doesn't matter if doSomething() returns a value or not, as it will not be used.

```
this.settings = this.settingsService.getSettings().map(settings => this.transformSettings(settings));
```

if you want to actually change the data you're sending to the display, the map operator is heavily used for this case. transformSettings() must return a value, the value that you want to display specifically, as this will be passed to the ultimate subscriber.

As for part 2, store the result in a behavior subject on your service layer so that it is always available to any component that needs it:

```
private settingsSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
settings$ = this.settingsSource.asObservable().filter(e => !!e); //this prevents the initial null value from being sent
loadSettings() {
    this.http.get('settings').map(r => r.json()).subscribe(this.settingsSource);
}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.loadSettings();
}
```

then have your components subscribe to settings$ and it will be there whenever it gets there.

Answer (score 0):

usually services in angular 2 return observables.
this is because http requests take a variable amount of time to return with data from the server.

im not sure what getsettings is doing exactly, but the general set-up would be the following:

```
//service layer
    function getSettings() {
        return this.http.get(`server-url`)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');
}
//in your component
this.service.getSettings().subscribe(result => {this.settings = result}, error => {console.log("there was an error.")});
```

the subscribe portion gets fired after the http request responds to the client.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things to help you along the way:

- The async pipe is great for if the data is ready to serve direct from the server. If you need it in the component dont use the async pipe just subscribe instead.
- Angular will give you back an observable from an http request, you then can use the subcribe() function and provide an actions you want to occur once the data is retrieved or if it fails.

[Here is a good tutorial on using http in an angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

In your particular case you want something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.settings = this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe((settings)=>{
    this.settings = settings;
    console.log("Logging Settings: " + this.settings);
}
```

To answer your second question, Angular services, if done as the devs intended, follow the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and are a shared resource through the entire app. This means everything that accesses it is receiving the same instance as anything else.

Comment: the async pipe is great even if the data needs transformation, this is what the map operator is for.

Comment: @bryan60 Read the rest of the line that mentions if you need it in the component...

Comment: I'd still disagree. You're better removing statefulness and committing to the reactive style and just combining observable streams. Situations where you need to subscribe in components are few and far between, and most of them involve reactive forms.

Comment: @bryan60 I am not sure what you are disagreeing with. My first statement was "Async pipes are great for data ready to serve from the server" which is true (regardless of if it will use a map function or not).  My second statement was "if you NEED it in the component (not if you want it) just subscribe to it in the component." Which is also true as it is the primary way to get it in the component.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with 1. that the async pipe is only useful for data ready to serve from the server, this isn't true.  async isn't just a syntactic sugar. It helps immensely with subscription management and preventing memory leaks and increases app performance by facilitating more use of onPush change detection 2. your statement implies that the data is usually needed in the component and that subscribing in component isn't a bad practice when it is, it should be avoided where ever possible.

Comment: @bryan60 Never said 'Only' not sure where you got that... And my other statement does not imply anything.... If you need it in the component class then you need it in the component class.

Comment: The async pipe is great for if the data is ready to serve direct from the server

conditional logic: great IF this (else not great)

Comment: @bryan60 Is that how conditionals actually work? Maybe read up on that.  When you write an If statement that doesn't pass, does everything inside become negated? (The answer is No)  `a = false; b =  false; if(a == true){ b = false} ` What does b equal?

Comment: you said async is great if data is ready. Your implication was clear dude, it's fine that you didn't know. you don't need to be so defensive.

Comment: @bryan60 Just trying to help ya out. If data is ready, no map needed, would you not use async pipe?

Comment: of course i would bc the async pipe should almost always be used. but from the context of your answer, it's clear that you meant it shouldn't be used if the data is not ready.  This is not the case.  I can't continue this back and forth so have a good one!

Comment: @bryan60 I wont keep arguing but here's a tip for you, extracting implications from text online will only make you look foolish. Same thing with quoting and adding words to the quote....